# Basic pdo oop in php

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm new in php oop..I'm having trouble in showing my fields value. I have here the ff classes.

```
public static function getAll()
{

    self::conn();

    try
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.guitar";

        $q = self::$db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute();
        $results = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,
                "Guitar",
                array('id', 'make', 'model', 'colour', 'price'));

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $results;    
}
```

I want it to show from diff fields. Here is my code:

```
$guitars = Guitar::getAll();
```

I can see the values when I try using the `print_r`

What I want is like this.

```
echo $row['field1'];  echo $row['field2'];
```

THank you in advance.

Comment: Having "classes" full of static methods and properties pretty much defeats the purpose of OOP.

Comment: @Radu that is some sorts of grouping. If its used for grouping then it should be okay.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, well yes, it _is_ grouping. But grouping is not OOP, that's what I'm saying. It's just namespaced functions and variables (in which the "class" acts as the namespace), not actual classes and objects (OOP).

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching result as objects, so you could do like this:

```
$guitars = Guitar::getAll();
foreach ($guitars as $guitar) {
  echo $guitar->getId();
  echo $guitar->getMake();
  // ... and so on
}
```

***Addtion:***

You need to have the constructor to set the property, and provide public methods to access the property.

```
class Guitar {
  private $id;
  private $make;
  private $model;
  private $color;
  private $price;

  public function __construct($id, $make, $model, $color, $price) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->make = $make;
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->color = $color;
    $this->price = $price;
  }

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getMake() {
    return $this->make;
  }
  // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It was declared as private. Is there any other way? I have these error "fatal error: Cannot access private property Guitar::$id", but is there any disadvantage if I put it public?

Comment: yes thank you very much. How can I show the values now?sorry, I'm newbee.

Comment: atal error: Call to a member function getMake() on a non-object :(

Comment: @user1693411 Did you write these code yourself, try do some debug :)

Comment: I'm still learning, new in debuggin. I've got this code from here [link]http://phpeasy.co.uk/tutorial-object-orientation-basics-part-4-implementing-crud-methods/#comments

Comment: THank very much for the time this code is working for me.`$guitars = Guitar::getAll();
foreach ($guitars as $guitar) {
  echo $guitar->getId();
  echo $guitar->getMake();
  // ... and so on
}`